# sum rows with a similar name in r

Tags: r, sum, rows

I have this table that has rows with similar or equal names I need to sum these rows. Make a single record, how can I do it using R. I try with a loop for doesn't work.

or (i in length(df1$variante)) {
+   if (df1$variante == "INTERNACIONAL" | df1$variante == " INTERNAC" ){
+     rbind(df1$variante)
+   }
+
+
+ }
Warning message:
In if (df1$variante == "INTERNACIONAL" | df1$variante == " INTERNAC") { :
  a condição tem comprimento > 1 e somente o primeiro elemento será usado

```
df_variante
                               x freq
1                                 259
2                  INTERNACIONAL  844
3                           GOLD 2164
4                GOLD EXECUTIVOS    2
5                        GRAFITE  109
6           GRAFITE INTERNACIONA  231
7                       INFINITE  546
8            INFINITE EXECUTIVOS    2
9                  INTERNACIONAL 4660
10                      NACIONAL 8390
11                       NANQUIM   12
12          NANQUIM INTERNACIONA   57
13                      PLATINUM 1407
14                         AZUL     9
15                     AZUL CARD  112
16                         BLACK  775
17                          GOLD 2872
18                 IN   INTERNAC    1
19                 IN   NACIONAL    7
20                 INTERNACIONAL 6678
21       MC ELECTRONIC GOV BAHIA    5
22                      NACIONAL 9692
23                      PLATINUM 1383
24               TIGRE  NACIONAL  207
25                 TURISMO  GOLD  337
26          TURISMO  INTERNACION  528
27             TURISMO  NACIONAL  841
28             TURISMO  PLATINUM   90
29                  TURISMO GOLD  322
30                 TURISMO INTER  531
31                 AMAZONIA GOLD    5
32        AMAZONIA INTERNACIONAL   14
33             AMAZONIA NACIONAL   19
34 EPIDEMIA CORINTHIANA PLATINUM    4
35                     JCB UNICO  203
36    UNIVERSITARIO  INTERNACION   92
37           UNIVERSITARIO INTER  262
```

Comment: When you say similar, can you show the expected output because there are lots of rows with `TURISMO` having different suffix

Answer (score 0):

If you want the rows where `freq` contains for example 'INTER'- you could maybe do:

```
sum(df_variante$freq[grep(df_variante$x,pattern='INTER')])
```

Here you are just using `grep` to search the `x` column for the pattern 'INTER'

I noticed there are some rows with something like 'IN NACIONAL'.

In this case you could do:

```
idxs=unique(c(grep(df_variante$x,pattern='INTER'),grep(df_variante$x,pattern='NACIONAL'),....)) #do this for all patterns of interest
df_sub=df_variante[idxs,]
```

BTW:
 your for loop in your question is not working because- your looping through the columns with `length` you want to loop through the rows:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df_variante)){....}
```

But that is only if you still want to do it that way